# React Native: Animated value's .setValue() doesn't work (Animated API)

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-animated

I've been struggling with making a specific animation using Animated API in React Native:

An accordion that expands, and 2 seconds after that, 3 buttons fade in one by one, with a stagger of 200ms.
This all works for me with the code below:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut, () => {
      isExpanding && animateButtonsFadeIn();
    });
    buttonsFadeArray.forEach((fadeValue) => fadeValue.setValue(0));
  }, [isExpanding]);
```

**Notes:**

- isExpanding is a state controlling whether the accordion is expanding or collapsing.
- animateButtonsFadeIn is a function that animates the buttons to fade-in one by one with a stagger of 200ms.
- If isExpanding = false, buttonsFadeArray's Animated.Values will be set to 0 in order to "clear" the buttons

The problem is, **the buttons are not cleared after I collapse the accordion!**
I know that because when I open it back again, I can still see the buttons, and the accordion is not "empty" for 2 seconds like its supposed to.

Would gladly appreciate any help and provide more code snippets to you guys